# jQuery.Post erroring out only in IE 11

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, jquery

I have a post back to a server I am running on, its pretty simple and works in chrome and firefox. But for some reason IE returns an invalid argument error. I cant find an explanation of what argument is invalid when debugging either. I'm not sure what is going on. I have a guess that the version of jQuery may have a bug in it since it's 1.7.2. I have not tried it in an older version of IE. Here is the post: Selected is simply an array of ids. Any ideas?

```
var response = jQuery.post('#', 
    { 'ids': JSON.stringify(selected), 'status' : true},
    function() {
        //alert('success');
    })
      .done(function() {
        alert('second success');
        initStatusDialog();
      })
      .fail(function(req, status, error) {
        console.log(req);
        console.log(status);
        console.log(error);
        //alert(status);
        alert('error');
      }, 'text');
```

Comment: The best place to debug things like this is the [Network](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn255004(v=vs.85).aspx) tab of the dev tools. In this tab you will be able to see exactly the data sent to the URL and also the exact response from the URL back ot your AJAX (post) call. Chrome and FireFox have this as well.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the latest version of jQuery? Even if it's not responsible for this bug, an outdated version will likely cause you problems later.

Comment: I'm doing a custom page in Netsuite, which provides jQuery on page. If it IS jQuery I can try and run a newer version in tandem. Honestly if I could I would update Netsuite's jQuery with the newest version. Mostly I'm concerned that it may be my code that is causing the problem. I want to make sure it isn't me before I go blaming the library or environment.